# How can I fix this Conflicting conformance error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I am trying to create a `ProfileCellController` that I can use to configure a cell in my `UITableView`.

As my table can have multiple cell types, I was hoping to use generics to set the type on the cell required and use a configure method to set the props.

This is what I have so far:

```swift
import UIKit

public protocol ProfileLoadedView {
  func display(_ viewModel: ProfileViewModel)
}

public class SingleLineCell: UITableViewCell { }
public class MultiLineWithIconCell: UITableViewCell { }

public final class ProfileCellController<T> where T: UITableViewCell {

  private var cell: T?

  func view(in tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell()
    return cell!
  }
}

extension ProfileCellController: ProfileLoadedView where T: SingleLineCell {
  public func display(_ viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {

  }
}

extension ProfileCellController: ProfileLoadedView where T: MultiLineWithIconCell {
  public func display(_ viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {

  }
}

extension UITableView {
  func dequeueReusableCell<T: UITableViewCell>() -> T {
    let identifier = String(describing: T.self)
    return dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
  }
}
```

However the second extension has an error of

> Conflicting conformance of 'ProfileCellController' to protocol 'ProfileLoadedView'; there cannot be more than one conformance, even with different conditional bounds

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly that's not supported yet. You cannot have several conditional conformances to the same protocol with different conditions.

However, you can make `ProfileCellController` unconditionally conform to the `ProfileLoadedView` protocol, provide a default implementation for the `display` method and then provide more specific implementations for the subclasses.

```
extension ProfileCellController: ProfileLoadedView {
  public func display(_ viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
    print("default")
  }
}

extension ProfileCellController where T: SingleLineCell {
    public func display(_ viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
        print("singleline")
    }
}

extension ProfileCellController where T: MultiLineWithIconCell {
  public func display(_ viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
    print("multiline")
  }
}

ProfileCellController<SingleLineCell>().display(ProfileViewModel()) // prints singleline
ProfileCellController<MultiLineWithIconCell>().display(ProfileViewModel()) // prints multiline
```

Comment: Good approach here as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a class and use some inheritance so your protocol could be just implemented once?

```
public class GenericCell: UITableViewCell { }
public class SingleLineCell: GenericCell { }
public class MultiLineWithIconCell: GenericCell { }

extension ProfileCellController: ProfileLoadedView where T: GenericCell {
  public func display(_ viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {

    switch cell {
     case is SingleLineCell:
      // impl goes here
      return
     case is MultiLineWithIconCell:
     // impl goes here
     return
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Let's imagine you have 100 cell classes.

Comment: Then I would try to find another approach, but in this case... he doesn't have 100 classes :/